# Having issue connecting to SoftLayer ObjectStorage using SFTP

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am having issue to connect to my SoftLayer ObjectStorage via SFTP by following the instructions listed on:
https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/connect-object-storage-using-sftp

When I tried to make the connection, it returns the following error message:

> Unable to negotiate with 173.192.119.113 port 22: no matching key
>   exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

I was trying to connect to dal05.objectstorage.softlayer.net endpoint but not successful. How do I correctly connect to ObjectStorage using SFTP.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can connect successfuly I just use the folowing command:

```
    sftp $user@dal05.objectstorage.softlayer.net

Note replace $user
```

The user and pass for you object storage can be found by:

Go https://control.softlayer.com
On the menu select Storage->Object Storage
Select an Account name from the list
Select the datacenter that you wish
Click on View Credentials

Regards

Comment: Thanks. I can connect to it now. But it was confusing as to what is accountID and portal user id.... but is clear after looking at the credentials. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

$ sftp -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1